# Using Glide inside custom ImageAdapter causing a jumping effect while scrolling

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter, android-glide

If someone is very knowledgeable about this topic, I am sincerely confused and would really appreciate any help I can get.

Problem: Scrolling down in the GridView works as expected, however when I scroll down (far enough to start recycling views) and then attempt to scroll back up, the GridView jumps all the way to the top of the List displaying the first items.

To Test: Scroll to bottom of list and then attempt to slowly scroll back to the top of the list. After about 6 rows or so, you will notice a bit of lag then it jumps to the top.

Notes: I have noticed that the more images I load into the GridView the more exaggerated the problem becomes. I feel like it must be a memory issue, but the problem happens (slightly) with even 10 images loaded into the GridView. If you have any questions, please ask them so I can help you guide me to a solution.

I have tried using other image loading API such as Picasso to no avail (Picasso was actually worse than Glide)

Areas of Interest: ImageAdapter's getView Method, MoviePosterFragments ASyncTask inner Class

Git: https://github.com/schliengerk/UdacityProjects/tree/master/PopularMovies

Comment: To solve, try without recycling views (do not use convertView, just always return a new view). What I suspect is that Glide hasn't finished yet with the old view, therefore you still see the first image. You can also try calling `Glide.clear` on the convertView.

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know

Comment: Both solutions did not fix the problem. However, it did make the jumpy scroll effect behave differently. instead of an instant jump, it scrolled to the top one at a time by itself.

Comment: Try not to scroll untill you confirm all the AsyncTasks (and notifyDataChanged calls) finished. Do you still have problem.

Comment: Yes I still have the problem.

Comment: Someone on another forum suggested it was due to a memory issue. I dont think this is the case, but maybe I am mistaken?

Comment: Makes no sense to be memory issue, as you have a maximum of 5-6 images at time.

Comment: I agree. I do not think it is a memory issue. Although this may not make any sense (im new to this), It seems like when I scroll up, the recycled image somehow is getting the position of "0" and its causing the list to reload from the beginning. This may not be possible, but it is what it looks like to me.

Comment: BTW, how big are the images you are downloading? If they are big, you may want to think of resizing them on the server.

Comment: The images are pretty large, and in theory I would resize them. However, this is not my current problem. Unless this is the problem, but I have experimented with resizing and it does not solve the issue.

Comment: If it's a memory issue, then that is definitely part of the problem. You could be downloading 10 images of 3mb each, when all you need is 20kb

Comment: Just tried it with the smalled image option available and it still has the same problem. I am quite confident it is not based on image size. I think I may have implemented the ImageAdapter Incorrectly. But I do not know what else I should be doing

Comment: Shameless Self Bump

Comment: Try same thing with images already downloaded to your device, without glide.

Comment: I have same problem. I am using local caching but I still experience this effect. @KurtisSchlienger did you find any solution? Also, point of interest: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/984